# REQUEST/REPLIES REST API .NET CORE

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

Client-side:
the client send a POST request to a web API REST using HTTPCLIENT to URL `"Http://localhost:44344/api/sale"`
with a JSON body:

```
{
    "CashierID":"002",
    "AdditionalInfo":
    [
    {
     "amount":"11",
     "sessionID":"2",
    }
    ]
}
```

Server-side:

Upon receiving the request, the server immediately returns a result with an Id to identify the operation, and forward the request to another server and wait for a response . Whenever the result is available, the server resend the response  with the result and Id to the same client.

```
{
"Result": {
        
        "ErrorCode": "",
        "OperationID": 1,
        "Status": null,
        "responseCode": null
    }
}
```

As I know in .NET Core, a method can return just one response, I do some searches, I found that a Queue System can do this but just on executing a multiple request not responses.
how can I do this approach of response?
Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this with HTTP, it would be against the HTTP communication model. If the server sends a response, that request/response is completed, you need a new one. It doesn't seem like HTTP is what you want for this - hint, server -> client communication is normally done through technologies like websockets.

Comment: This simply isn't possible with HTTP. You can't send multiple responses to the same request. Options: 1) wait for the 2nd server to respond before providing a response from your API. 2) Use websockets instead of HTTP to allow for a stream of real-time updates initiated by either client or server. (in .NET world this is generally done with SignalR, btw.) 3) Find some other asynchronous way to notify the user when the response comes back from the other server (e.g. email, SMS, push notification).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thank you for your response, what about client make a polling request and get the second response? the problem how to store a response before starting a pooling, i thought also this solution but i don't know how can i do this

Comment: @ADyson thank you, 1) getting a response take a long time, that what because i need this approach.  2) i need to use rest communication.   3) like what?

Comment: 2) why, specifically? We've just explained why this isn't a realistic option in your situation. You need to be pragmatic. 3) I already gave 3 examples for this.

Comment: 2) because it's what it asked me to use.( i can't choice), i have to use a Rest communication.  3) i didn't note it excuse me. now i understand. Thank you

Comment: "it asked me"...what / who asked you? Maybe you should go back to whoever it is and explain it's not a very good solution, and suggest a better way. As developers, we should not just blindly do as we're told (unless it's an exam situation or something), we should use our initiative to improve things when we have better knowledge.

Comment: If you really, genuinely, **must** use HTTP, then you're stuck with the polling approach, which as you know is not very efficient. That's all you can do (apart from augmenting the solution with the ideas from option 3, as a workaround).

Comment: @ADyson i agree with you, i have to explain them that it not a good solution and i will try to found a good solution. iknow also the polling has their disadvantages, so i need to find an other solution.  thanks anyway

Comment: if you rely on the odata you can achieve what you need, take a look here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/all-in-one-with-odata-batch/